# How to connect to sbt shell in IntelliJ and run a task?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

Since Intellij 2017.1 there has been a new sbt shell which keeps running on the background and is a bit faster.

I would like to replace the buggy sbt plugin running with a new configuration that connects to this shell and runs tasks I want.

This could be especially benefiting when running separate Unit tests from the IDE ()

Answer (score 1):

This currently isn't implemented in the Scala plugin, but there are some open tickets relating to this feature:

- ["SBT Task" run configurations should be able to run/debug in shell](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11748)
- [run configs: support running from sbt shell](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11565)
- [sbt shell tasks as before-run tasks in run configurations](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11995)

Please vote on these issues and feel free to add any thoughts as comments so that we know what is important to you.

Comment: I just voted, I definitely need this as I was working on a remote machine (windows workstation), somehow it is very slow when I have SBT Task running.